# Is the behavior behind the Shellshock vulnerability in Bash documented or at all intentional?

Tags: bash, function, security, environment-variables, shellshock-bash-bug

A recent vulnerability, [CVE-2014-6271](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-6271), in how [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) interprets environment variables [was disclosed](https://securityblog.redhat.com/2014/09/24/bash-specially-crafted-environment-variables-code-injection-attack/). The exploit relies on Bash parsing some environment variable declarations as function definitions, but then continuing to execute code following the definition:

```
$ x='() { echo i do nothing; }; echo vulnerable' bash -c ':'
vulnerable
```

But I don't get it. There's nothing I've been able to find in the Bash manual about interpreting environment variables as functions at all (except for *inheriting functions*, which is different). Indeed, a proper named function definition is just treated as a value:

```
$ x='y() { :; }' bash -c 'echo $x'
y() { :; }
```

But a corrupt one prints nothing:

```
$ x='() { :; }' bash -c 'echo $x'

$ # Nothing but newline
```

The corrupt function is unnamed, and so I can't just call it. Is this vulnerability a pure implementation bug, or is there an intended feature here, that I just can't see?

### Update

Per Barmar's comment, I hypothesized the name of the function was the parameter name:

```
$ n='() { echo wat; }' bash -c 'n'
wat
```

Which I could swear I tried before, but I guess I didn't try hard enough. It's repeatable now. Here's a little more testing:

```
$ env n='() { echo wat; }; echo vuln' bash -c 'n'
vuln
wat
$ env n='() { echo wat; }; echo $1' bash -c 'n 2' 3 -- 4

wat
```

…so apparently the args are not set at the time the exploit executes.

Anyway, the basic answer to my question is, *yes, this is how Bash implements inherited functions*.

Comment: How do you think inheriting functions works in the first place? The only type of inheritance available between processes is the environment. So exported functions have to be encoded in the environment somehow.

Comment: the example code in the link you included starts with `env`, as in `env x='...`. Not sure how this makes a difference either. FYI `ksh` does not emit any output from these tests after changing references from `bash -c` to `ksh -c`.

Comment: The lastet bash 4.3.25-1 closed the execution of the command after the strange function definition, but the function is still get defined...

Comment: There is a new vulnerability coming down the pipe as well **https://access.redhat.com/security/cve/CVE-2014-7169**

Comment: Defining a function this way is an intended feature; the bug is the extra code following the function definition being executed as well.

Comment: @chepner:  To get this straight, can we still have this:  `export ls='(){ /bin/ls $@; echo "Caught you";}'`?

Comment: Almost. The string must begin *explicitly* with `() {` (note the space). Otherwise, yes, `bash` will turn that into a function called `ls` if it sees that string in its environment on startup. The closing brace, it turns out, is somewhat optional.

Comment: @Barmar in my defense, I actually didn't know what _inherit_ meant. Consider that you can set x=3 and access it in a subshell: `$(echo $x)`, but that's subtly different from exporting `x`. Until this bug came to light I didn't even know you could export functions.

Comment: See [What does env x='() { :;}; command' bash do and why is it insecure?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157329)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This seems like an implementation bug.

Apparently, the way exported functions work in `bash` is that they use specially-formatted environment variables. If you export a function:

```
f() { ... }
```

it defines an environment variable like:

```
f='() { ... }'
```

What's probably happening is that when the new shell sees an environment variable whose value begins with `()`, it prepends the variable name and executes the resulting string. The bug is that this includes executing anything *after* the function definition as well.

The fix described is apparently to parse the result to see if it's a valid function definition. If not, it prints the warning about the invalid function definition attempt.

[This article](http://fedoramagazine.org/shellshock-how-does-it-actually-work/) confirms my explanation of the cause of the bug. It also goes into a little more detail about how the fix resolves it: not only do they parse the values more carefully, but variables that are used to pass exported functions follow a special naming convention. This naming convention is different from that used for the environment variables created for CGI scripts, so an HTTP client should never be able to get its foot into this door.

Comment: How come environment variables let you execute functions but not bash commands directly.

Comment: It's not "letting" you do anything. Bash uses these specially-formatted environment variables as the way to inherit functions. If it's not formatted like this, there's no reason to execute it, it's just plain data.

Answer (score 16):

The following:

```
x='() { echo I do nothing; }; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'typeset -f'
```

prints

```
vulnerable
x () 
{ 
    echo I do nothing
}
declare -fx x
```

seems, than Bash, after having parsed the `x=...`, discovered it as a function, exported it, saw the `declare -fx x` and allowed the execution of the command after the declaration.

`echo vulnerable`

```
x='() { x; }; echo vulnerable' bash -c 'typeset -f'
```

prints:

```
vulnerable
x () 
{ 
    echo I do nothing
}
```

and running the `x`

```
x='() { x; }; echo Vulnerable' bash -c 'x'
```

prints

```
Vulnerable
Segmentation fault: 11
```

segfaults - infinite recursive calls

It doesn't overrides already defined function

```
$ x() { echo Something; }
$ declare -fx x
$ x='() { x; }; echo Vulnerable' bash -c 'typeset -f'
```

prints:

```
x () 
{ 
    echo Something
}
declare -fx x
```

e.g. the x remains the previously (correctly) defined function.

For the Bash `4.3.25(1)-release` the vulnerability is closed, so

```
x='() { echo I do nothing; }; echo Vulnerable' bash -c ':'
```

prints

```
bash: warning: x: ignoring function definition attempt
bash: error importing function definition for `x'
```

but - **what is strange** (at least for me)

```
x='() { x; };' bash -c 'typeset -f'
```

STILL PRINTS

```
x () 
{ 
    x
}
declare -fx x
```

and the

```
x='() { x; };' bash -c 'x'
```

segmentation faults too, so it STILL accept the strange function definition...

Comment: Your last test, showing `x` not being overridden, actually looks like a bug as well. I would expect the command environment override to take precedence; it does, at least, for "normal" environment variables. Consider `declare -x foo=5; bash -c 'echo $foo'; foo=9 bash -c 'echo $foo'`. The first outputs 5; the second outputs 9.

Comment: RE: update 2, that's the function export working as expected. The string assigned to `x` is a function definition and nothing more, so it is exported.

Comment: You can't define a function that way, at least not explicitly. Only an instance of `bash` that inherits such a value will "instantiate" it as an executable function. That is, with `export foo='() { echo 5; }'`, `foo` will remain a normal string parameter in the current shell, but a child `bash` will make it a function (`echo $foo` would print nothing, for example, because there is no parameter named `foo` in the child, just a function).

Comment: From what I can tell, this is *exactly* what `bash` did: it evaluated any string in the environment whose *prefix* was a valid function definition, without regard for whatever trailing code was evaluated along with it.

Comment: the vulnerability is NOT closed, the fix is incomplete and just make harder to use the vulnerability.
CVE-2014-6271 has been closed, but CVE-2014-7169 has been opened.
Another patch will follow.
cheers

Answer (score 13):

I think it's worth looking at the Bash code itself. [The patch](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.3-patches/bash43-025) gives a bit of insight as to the problem. In particular,

```
*** ../bash-4.3-patched/variables.c 2014-05-15 08:26:50.000000000 -0400
--- variables.c 2014-09-14 14:23:35.000000000 -0400
***************
*** 359,369 ****
      strcpy (temp_string + char_index + 1, string);

!     if (posixly_correct == 0 || legal_identifier (name))
!       parse_and_execute (temp_string, name, SEVAL_NONINT|SEVAL_NOHIST);
!
!     /* Ancient backwards compatibility.  Old versions of bash exported
!        functions like name()=() {...} */
!     if (name[char_index - 1] == ')' && name[char_index - 2] == '(')
!       name[char_index - 2] = '\0';

      if (temp_var = find_function (name))
--- 364,372 ----
      strcpy (temp_string + char_index + 1, string);

!     /* Don't import function names that are invalid identifiers from the
!        environment, though we still allow them to be defined as shell
!        variables. */
!     if (legal_identifier (name))
!       parse_and_execute (temp_string, name, SEVAL_NONINT|SEVAL_NOHIST|SEVAL_FUNCDEF|SEVAL_ONECMD);

      if (temp_var = find_function (name))
```

When Bash exports a function, it shows up as an environment variable, for example:

```
$ foo() { echo 'hello world'; }
$ export -f foo
$ cat /proc/self/environ | tr '\0' '\n' | grep -A1 foo
foo=() {  echo 'hello world'
}
```

When a new Bash process finds a function defined this way in its environment, it evalutes the code in the variable using `parse_and_execute()`. For normal, non-malicious code, executing it simply defines the function in Bash and moves on. However, because it's passed to a generic execution function, Bash will correctly parse and execute *additional code* defined in that variable after the function definition.

You can see that in the new code, a flag called `SEVAL_ONECMD` has been added that tells Bash to only evaluate the first command (that is, the function definition) and `SEVAL_FUNCDEF` to only allow functio0n definitions.

Answer (score 0):

In regard to your question about documentation, notice here in the commandline documentation for the `env` command, that a study of the syntax shows that `env` is working as documented.

- There are, optionally, 4 possible options
- An optional hyphen as a synonym for `-i` (for backward compatibility I assume)
- Zero or more NAME=VALUE pairs. These are the variable assignment(s) which could include function definitions.
- Note that no semicolon (;) is required between or following the assignments.
- The last argument(s) can be a single command followed by its argument(s). It will run with whatever permissions have been granted to the login being used. Security is controlled by restricting permissions on the login user and setting permissions on user-accessible executables such that users other than the executable's owner can only read and execute the program, not alter it.

> ```
> [ spot@LX03:~ ] env --help
> Usage: env [OPTION]... [-] [NAME=VALUE]... [COMMAND [ARG]...]
> Set each NAME to VALUE in the environment and run COMMAND.
>
>   -i, --ignore-environment   start with an empty environment
>   -u, --unset=NAME           remove variable from the environment
>       --help     display this help and exit
>       --version  output version information and exit
>
> A mere - implies -i.  If no COMMAND, print the resulting environment.
>
> Report env bugs to bug-coreutils@gnu.org
> GNU coreutils home page: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
> General help using GNU software: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>
> Report env translation bugs to <http://translationproject.org/team/>
> ```