# Shellshock vulnerability, CVE-2014-7169

Tags: linux, bash, shellshock-bash-bug

This [ycombinator thread](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8365100) states that

```
env X='() { (a)=>\' sh -c "echo date"
```

allows you to drop the first token, and then run the result, sending the output to the dropped token. I can see that the magic is in the `() { (a)=>\'` part, but this is quite a hard thing to search for, so it would be great if someone could explain the inner workings.

In the linked possible duplicate question, a variable is exported to an environment variable by using,

```
env X="() { :;} ;
```

which really is not the same as

```
env X='{ (a)=>\'
```

which is the part I am trying to understand the workings off. So, what do the `(a)` and `=>\'` parts do? Clearly, it is doing something very similar, but is different in that it got around the first patch to this vulnerability, see comments by chepner.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/157329/31347 http://stackoverflow.com/q/26052189/251311

Comment: Yes, all distros are aware and most have patched versions available. If you cannot use your distro's update, then build bash from source (see: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/). You may also need to update `readline` to support the current bash. (`readline 6.3` required)

Comment: @zerkms Neither of your links explains the more complicated attack in this question, which works even with the initial Shell Shock patch.

Comment: I made a (rather feeble) attempt at explaining this example at http://stackoverflow.com/q/26041934/1126841.

Comment: @chepner. Thanks for that and noting that my question relates to the newer attack -- the fact that it remains unanswered (at least fully) suggests there is something very clever and evil here.

Comment: You can see patches to address this vector as well at ftp.bash.org as well. They don't appear to be widely deployed yet (blame the weekend); the hole they patch is a just a little harder to explain than simply "blindly evaluates the entire value". In a nutshell, though, the problem involves a lookahead failure in the parser.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy. Thanks. The edit to that other question, where the OP asks about env X='() { (a)=>\' has not been answered yet, whereas the original question has. As such, I think there is some validity to leaving this question open.

Comment: @JohnBarça, yes, the one it's a duplicate of hasn't been answered, but why would having two unanswered duplicate questions unanswered and open be better than one?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/26041934/539394 which has an answer.