# why does bash set command list functions

Tags: bash, shell

Why does the builtin BASH command *set* print shell functions?  My searches on Google, and even Stack Overflow, haven't produced a satisfactory answer.  From the [manual page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=bash&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=CentOS%207.1&arch=default&format=html#SHELL_BUILTIN_COMMANDS), "Without options, *the name and value of each shell variable* are displayed ... ."  With options doesn't change this. Functions aren't variables ... are they?

For reference, this became a problem when I was using *set* to test for the existence of a variable:

```
set_version() {
    if [[ ! $(set | grep -q PKG_VERSION_STAMP) ]]; then
        echo Version not set.  Using default
        PKG_VERSION_STAMP=0.1
    fi
    echo Package Version: $PKG_VERSION_STAMP
}
```

I tested the conditional construction from the interactive shell, and it worked, but that's because I hadn't defined it in a function.  My script failed because the function was defined and the grep passed.  Consequently, the variable, `PKG_VERSION_STAMP`, was never defined.

Incidentally, changing from *set* to *env* fixes the problem.  I'd just like to know why BASH considers *functions to be variables* and print their contents.

Comment: That's not a good way to test for the presence of a variable. Much better to just test for it having a value (and/or being null) with the `:-` [expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02). Or Use `:=` to assign it a value when one doesn't already exist. I can't find anything about why `set` shows variables in the spec. I wonder if non-bash shells do that.

Comment: @EtanReisner wow thank you.  I hadn't read, or known, of those expansions before now.  That's very helpful.

Comment: The question rather is:  why should it not?  The implementation of the shell functions is quite similar to the shell variables which are also shown using `set`.  Introducing another built-in command (similar to `set`) for showing the shell functions would have no real advantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you want to have the `set` builtin not listing the shell functions, you can switch to `bash` posix mode:

```
$ set -o posix
$ set
...
```

While not documented in its manual, it is a well known fact since the [shellshock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022248/is-the-behavior-behind-the-shellshock-vulnerability-in-bash-documented-or-at-all) vulnerability exposition that `bash` is storing its functions as special variables.

Comment: Interesting.  I've not heard of this bug and certainly didn't stumble across it while looking for an answer to my question (which I did do before posting the question).  Thanks a lot for this.  This is also from the manual page, "In posix mode, only shell variables are listed."  However, the manual page specifically states, beforehand, that this builtin **only lists** shell variables and their values.